# Turkish character file name

Tags: html, laravel, apache

I have a image on my website with that name.

```
Yaşar.png
```

But when I tried to use it in `<img src="https://example.com/Yaşar.png">` tag, it looks broken.

Comment: you need to encode your url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<img src="http://example.com/Yaşar.png">
```

If it doesn't work cross-check your image extension.

Comment: Didn't work. Weird thing is, I can use same image with same name on my other hosting. This problem occurred when I deployed on azure. Could it bi apache related ?